ERROR Failed to execute program: Instruction bfunc is not supported
When I ran a circuit on ibm_brisbane I got the following error :
ERROR Failed to execute program: Instruction bfunc is not supported
I don't know why that error occurs. I found this related post, and according to the post it seems like the error occurs due to the lack of support for a classical conditional on the real device. In fact, the circuit I ran includes a classical conditional, c_if, but I believe that's already supported by ibm_brisbane?
I'd appreciate any hints.
(btw, my qiskit ver is 1.2.0)

This is a known issue, which should hopefully be resolved soon.

I see, thanks for the info!

In the meantime you can use if_test instead of c_if.

thanks, if_test worked with optimization_level=3.

you can write that into an answer.

Note that c_if is about to be deprecated: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/pull/13223
